# How many ways we can achieve the Inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Hi I am trying to understand the Inheritance concept in JavaScript, I was read many tutorials and many you-tube videos. Still I am confusing could please some one explain me

what are the ways we will achieve the inheritance in JavaScript

Some One saying  :

```
Object.create(ParentObject);
```

Someone saying :

```
Object.prototype = ParentObject;
```

Some one saying :

```
object.__porto__.__proto__ = parentObject.portotype.
```

I am confused, could you please help me out. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: None of those look exactly right, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, i Read many times, But Still confusing. if do you have any experience with coding please provide me some example code, it great help to me, Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @Coder, there's only one type of inheritance in JS, and that is *prototypal inheritance*. And that boils down to: *pretty much everything in JS inherits from some other (regular) Object that works as it's prototype. It's a cascade, and it can be modified. Unlike classes wich work as blueprints for the objects to build.* But there have to be tons of articles on this topic on SO and the web, wich explain this in all it's details. The snippets in your question only show different ways to play with the same mechanisms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Inheritance

Inheritance can be done in JavaScript using functions. Although this doesn't seem as easy as the common "public class Child extends Parent," you'll get used to it.

### Examples

When creating an object in JavaScript, you write the following:

```
var object = {};
```

You would then add to your object using object.variable = value; or the following:

```
var object = {
    variable: 0,
    otherVariable: "String"
}
```

So when you want to use the same functions/variables in multiple objects - inheritance - you would do the following:

```
var object = inheritedFunction({});

function inheritedFunction(options) {
    var that = {
        variable = 0,
        otherVariable = "String"
    }

    that.update = function () {
        // Function
    }

    return that;
};
```

Doing the above automatically give the object the update function and all of the prewritten variables.

Feel free to comment any questions you may have!

Comment: this is (Object) composition, you're explaining, not inheritance.

Comment: He did not ask for an explanation of inheritance, but rather the number of ways it could be done and I was contributing. @Thomas

Comment: still, composition ain't inheritance. One of the key-features of inheritance in JS is, that you can modify the prototype, and these changes will immediately appear on every (already existing) instance. That doesn't work with composition. Or you can change the prototype of an object, and this object immediately "gets" the methods of the new prototype, and "loses" the methods of the old one.

Comment: Yes @Flizzet, Thanks for Your Answer. but need to understand what are the various types of Inheritance in JS. Any examples.

Comment: @Thomas any help from your side, Great help to me. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas, could you please help me out for Solution.